# Inserting element Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst=[5,6,7,8,9]
v=10
for item in lst:
        if item<v:
            lst.insert(0,v)
print(lst)
```

i want to insert 10, at the index 0 if all the elements in the list are under 10, im not tryning to insert 10 each time

so it should look like this : [10,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: Do not mutate a list while iterating over it. This would work: `lst = [v for item in lst if item < v] + lst`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski i dont want a one-liner

Comment: Turn the one-liner into something longer by appending to a list of items you want to prepend inside your loop.  And then after your loop do the assignment `lst = prepend_items + lst` or if you really need to mutate the original object `lst[0:0] = prepend_items`.

Comment: Your loop never ends because after you insert an item at index zero the next iteration points to the item you just iterated over because it is now shifted one space to the right.

Comment: Another strategy that would fix your code is to iterate over a copy: `for item in lst[:]:`.  This way the mutations to the original list will not affect iteration.  Do note that insertions at index 0 are algorithmically inefficient because each insertion requires every subsequent element to be shifted one space to the right.  In other words each insertion requires full iteration over the entire data structure.  With a large list with a large number of insertions the slowdown would be exponential.

Comment: i found a better way, so if item is less than v: set match=True and then if match: insert the number

Comment: If all of that is happening inside your loop you are still going to encounter a never ending loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting the same value of `v` at the beginning of the original list based on how many of the original values are less than `v`. In this case, preservation of insertion order is moot.

All inserted values are the same and are prepended to an original list that doesn't change.

So why not use something this

```
lst = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
v =  10
count = 0
for item in lst:
    if item < v:
        count += 1
new_lst = [v] * count + lst
print(new_lst)
```

Result

`>>> [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

---

**Edit:** Updating answer based on further clarification

> i want to insert 10, at the index 0 if **all** the elements in the
>   list are under 10, im not tryning to insert 10 each time

```
lst = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
v = 10
for item in lst[:]:
  if item < v:
    lst.insert(0, v)
    break
print(lst)
```

Result

`>>> [10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

The updated code will insert `v` at index `0` only once if a single item is less than `v`. When the `item < v` condition is met the for loop ends without checking any of the remaining items. Otherwise, if None of the values are less than `v`, you will traverse the entirety of your list without making any changes.

Notice that I used the insert method here since this code will shift all of your `lst` items only once.

Comment: i only want to include 10 one time

Comment: So what you are really after is the insertion of 10 if *any* of the elements in the list are below `v`? Currently, your example code implies that you are wanting to insert 10 *each* time you find an item less than `v`.

Comment: i want to insert 10, at the index 0 if all the elements in the list are under 10, im not tryning to insert 10 each time

Comment: Ok I updated the answer. However, I suggest editing your original question to reflect what you stated here in the comments.